# Не работает бот в телеграме. PyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, бот

```
import telebot as tl
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
import sqlite3
import time

conn = sqlite3.connect("D:/Promo_Bot/codes.db", check_same_thread=False)
cur = conn.cursor()
bot = tl.TeleBot("token")

admin = [564039295]

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    id = call.message.caption[4:len(call.message.caption)]
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM main WHERE id=?", (int(id),))
    print(id)
    if call.data == 'yes':
        print(id, 'yes')
        cur.execute("UPDATE main SET status=? WHERE id=?", ('accepting', int(id)))
    if call.data == 'no':
        print(id, 'no')
        cur.execute("UPDATE main SET status=? WHERE id=?", ('rejecting', int(id)))
    conn.commit()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def photo(message):
    print("photo")
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM main WHERE id=?", (message.caption,))
    if message.caption != None:
        if message.caption.isnumeric() and len(message.caption) == 7:
            if cur.fetchall() == []:
                bot.reply_to(message, "Запрос отправлен на модерацию")
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO main VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (str(message.caption), str(message.chat.id), 'waiting', str(message.photo[0].file_id), ''))
                conn.commit()
            else:
                bot.reply_to(message, "Этот код чека уже зарегестрирован")
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message, "Недействительный код чека")
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Отправте номер на чеке и фото одним сообщениеы")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start_for_all'])
def check(message):
    print("start_for_all")
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM main WHERE status='accepting'")
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            bot.send_message(int(row[1]), "Чек с кодом " + str(row[0]) + " был подтверждён")
            cur.execute("UPDATE main SET status='accepted' WHERE id=?", (row[0],))

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM main WHERE status='rejecting'")
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            bot.send_message(int(row[1]), "Чек с кодом " + str(row[0]) + " был отклонён")
            cur.execute("UPDATE main SET status='rejected' WHERE id=?", (row[0],))
        conn.commit()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start_for_admin'])
def check_admin(message):
    print("start_for_admin")
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM main WHERE status='waiting'")
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            for us in admin:
                markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Принять", callback_data='yes'), InlineKeyboardButton("Отклонить", callback_data='no'))
                mes = bot.send_photo(us, row[3], caption="Код:" + str(row[0]), reply_markup=markup)
                cur.execute("UPDATE main SET mes=? WHERE id=?", (str(list(row[4]) + [mes.message_id, mes.chat.id]), row[0]))
        cur.execute("UPDATE main SET status='wait' WHERE status='waiting'")
        conn.commit()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет")

@bot.message_handler()
def no(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Отправте номер на чеке и фото одним сообщение")

bot.polling()
```

После написания команд start_for_all или start_for_admin все остальные функции перестают работать.
Как я понимаю это из-за while, но до этого всё работало и с этой функцией, сейчас перестало.
Помогите пофиксить, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вначале добавьте

```
import threading
```

и

```
@bot.message_handler()
def no(message):
   bot.reply_to(message, "Отправте номер на чеке и фото одним сообщение")
```

заменить на

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
if message.text.lower() == 'start_for_admin':
    thread_start_for_all = threading.Thread(target=check_admin , args(message,))
    thread_start_for_all.start() 

elif message.text.lower() == 'start_for_all':
    thread_start_for_all = threading.Thread(target=check , args=(message,))
    thread_start_for_all.start() 

else:
    thread_photo = threading.Thread(target=photo , args=(message,))
    thread_photo.start()
```

- работа с таблицей реализована ужасно, постоянные ошибки, решил не лезть